# A metric convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I show that if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ and $(y_n)$ converges to $y$, then $d(x_n, y_n)$ converges to $d(x, y)$ in a formal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any given $\epsilon\gt 0,$ there are $N_1, N_2\in\Bbb{N}$ that gives $d(x_n,x)\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}2\ \forall n\ge N_1$ and $d(y_n,y)\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}2\ \forall n\ge N_2.$ The triangle inequality gives us $$d(x_n, y_n)\le d(x_n,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y_n)$$ and $$d(x, y)\le d(x,x_n)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y).$$ Therefore $$|d(x_n, y_n)-d(x,y)|\le d(x_n,x)+d(y_n,y)\lt\epsilon\,\,\,\,\ \forall n\ge\max\{N_1,N_2\}.$$
Hence in $\Bbb{R},$ the sequence $\left(d(x_n,y_n)\right)$ converges to $d(x,y).$

Comment: So this observation comes from triangle inequality? How can I improve this proof ?

Comment: Yes it comes from the triangle inequality. I complete my answer by adding more details. I hope this will helps you.

Comment: Yes, everything is so clear right now, thank you very much!